# p:selectCheckboxMenu lazy initialization

Tags: primefaces, lazy-loading, checkboxlist

I didn't find a `lazy` attribute in `p:selectCheckboxMenu`, so I thought about firing an event when the `ui-selectcheckboxmenu-trigger` component is clicked. It's the button with an arrow similar to the one in comboboxes:

[image: trigger button]

That's what I tried to do:

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu label="Channel" id="channels" value="#{managedBean.selectedChannels}">
    <f:selectItems id="channelItems" value="#{managedBean.channels}" var="obj" itemLabel="#{obj.category}" itemValue="#{obj}" />
    <p:ajax event="toggleSelect" listener="#{managedBean.initChannels}" update="channelItems" />
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>`
```

Debugged and found out `initChannels` method is not being called.

Comment: Correct, since there is nothing to select, the toggleSelect cannot fire.

Comment: But it's the `change` event which is being used for selection of an option

Comment: but the drop down will be closed after update. and you don't want initChannels to be called each time drop down is opened.

Comment: I'm already checking if collection is null before populating it

Comment: Yes and the toggle select is fired when? (according to the [DOCS](https://speakerdeck.com/player/827b32202f6f01321c076e02156363ec?slide=404#)): _when toggle all selecbox changes_

Comment: That's correct. So there isn't an event for what I need?

Comment: The particular page is taking 15 seconds to load, but the most important queries (necessary for basic use) finish in 6s. The other 9s is only combobox populating; being more specific, it happens in 6 `selectCheckMenu`s. Wouldn't want to change it to `autoComplete` since its multiple selection screws the layout. Maybe if it's possible to make an arrow to scroll content, if field gets too short... I also don't mind being forced to build a custom component, only problem is lack of knowledge.